# CSS and JS fails right after loading finished in codeigniter

Tags: jquery, css, codeigniter, twitter-bootstrap

I have downloaded bootstrap admin template from internet. When I place that in localhost, it worked. When I transferred that set of files in my codeigniter app resources folder, it loads correctly before page is fully loaded, but, after browser finishes loading, CSS and JS effects  disappears.

I do not know what to show to clarify my problem. Helping hands are appreciated.

```
<link id="bs-css" href="http://localhost/wiyohk/app/resources/admin/css/bootstrap-cerulean.css" rel="stylesheet">
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
  .sidebar-nav {
    padding: 9px 0;
  }
</style>
<link href="http://localhost/wiyohk/app/resources/admin/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://localhost/wiyohk/app/resources/admin/css/charisma-app.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="http://localhost/wiyohk/app/resources/admin/css/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href='http://localhost/wiyohk/app/resources/admin/css/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='http://localhost/wiyohk/app/resources/admin/css/fullcalendar.print.css' rel='stylesheet'  media='print'>
<link href='http://localhost/wiyohk/app/resources/admin/css/chosen.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='http://localhost/wiyohk/app/resources/admin/css/uniform.default.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='http://localhost/wiyohk/app/resources/admin/css/colorbox.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='http://localhost/wiyohk/app/resources/admin/css/jquery.cleditor.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='http://localhost/wiyohk/app/resources/admin/css/jquery.noty.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='http://localhost/wiyohk/app/resources/admin/css/noty_theme_default.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='http://localhost/wiyohk/app/resources/admin/css/elfinder.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='http://localhost/wiyohk/app/resources/admin/css/elfinder.theme.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='http://localhost/wiyohk/app/resources/admin/css/jquery.iphone.toggle.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='http://localhost/wiyohk/app/resources/admin/css/opa-icons.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<link href='http://localhost/wiyohk/app/resources/admin/css/uploadify.css' rel='stylesheet'>
```

This is the css linking I got after doing view source. When I click css files in view source part, i see all of the necessary css classes but when i inspect element and click css files it shows empty.

Comment: see what result is produces in firebug of firefox

Comment: I dont know why id="bs-css" has been used. I deleted that and It worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. I think i know the problem.
First the styles are loaded.
Then when page is fully loaded javascript or jquery runs and try to change the styles using the `id='bs-cs'`. The paths defined for javascript are not correct therefore the styles are gone. The same problem has occured to me i am sure if you correct the paths in javascript file everything will work fine. In the current scanrio as you have removed the attribute id you wont be able to use any other theme. The default theme will be loaded always. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why id="bs-css" has been used. I deleted that and It worked fine